# Wrong parsed ENTRYPOINT in windows Dockerfile

Tags: java, windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I wrote a Dockerfile that should build a windows image with java jdk inside. The entrypoint is pretty simple, it is just launching the java.exe.

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

COPY .\install_files\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe C:\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe
COPY .\install_files\agent.jar C:\agent.jar

SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]
RUN Start-Process -Filepath C:\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=C:\Java,/L,java.log" ; `
    $env:Path += ';C:\Java\bin'

SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "C:\agent.jar"] 
CMD ["-jnlpUrl", "my_localhost", "-secret", "your_secret", "-workDir", "'C:\Jenkins'"]
```

The building process succeeds: `docker build -t winwithjava:latest .`

But when I try `docker run --name winjava001`, the error message is:

> '["java"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I searched for the stopped container and retrieved the command executed (`docker ps -a --no-trunc`):

> "cmd /S /C java -jar C:\agent.ja r 'cmd /S /C [\"-jnlpUrl\",
>   \"http://localhost:8080/blabla\", \"-secret\", \"secret\",
>   \"-workDir\", \"'C:\Jenkins'\"]'"

Here I noticed that a shell is prepended to both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` but it seems the json has not been parsed at all. I checked inside the doc and it explicitly says this is the preferred way to specify an entrypoint ad set default arguments. My only doubt is this sentence in the [reference](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#shell):

> The following instructions can be affected by the SHELL instruction
>   when the *shell* form of them is used in a Dockerfile: RUN, CMD and
>   ENTRYPOINT.

So is it caused by `SHELL` statement? Because I used the *exec* form. I will not question the implementation choice, I just do not understand why the *exec* form is the preferred one and the `SHELL` statement does only affect those in *shell* form. But I am probably missing something.

Anyway, how can I write this Dockerfile so that the `CMD` arguments can be overridden?

The only idea I came up with was using a different entrypoint:

```
["Write-Output", "'Jenkins agent started'", ";", "&", "'java'", "-jar", "'C:\agent.jar'"]
```

And deleting the second `SHELL` statement. But again the json is not parsed correctly, like in the previous case (but now using `powershell -command`).

Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:26:49 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.2
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.8
  Git commit:       6a30dfc
  Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:39:49 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

---

**EDIT**

I tried with this basic dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

COPY .\install_files\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe C:\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe
COPY .\install_files\agent.jar C:\agent.jar

RUN powershell -command Start-Process -Filepath C:\jdk-8u221-windows-x64.exe -passthru -wait -argumentlist "/s,INSTALLDIR=C:\Java,/L,java.log" ; `
    $env:Path += ';C:\Java\bin'

CMD ["java", "-jar", "C:\agent.jar", "-jnlpUrl", "http://localhost:8080/xxx/slave-agent.jnlp", "-secret", "mysecret", "-workDir", "C:\Jenkins"]
```

But still the command launched (wrong) is:

```
cmd /S /C [\"java\", \"-jar\", \"C:\\agent.jar\", \"-jnlpUrl\", \"http://localhost:8080/computer/windows001/slave-agent.jnlp\", \"-secret\", \"cefcfcfd09b91c09ce5c26b552be9b026ddc0674d1b28a9e8722a9630400ee1b\", \"-workDir\", \"C:\\Jenkins\"]
```